# JSON.NET (de)serialize object references

Tags: c#, object, serialization, reference, json.net

If I serialize references to objects they are serialized as complete copy from the original object. That produces a lot of overhead if the objects are used multiple times.
What I want is that the list of object references is serialized into a list of object-ids and when deserialized reversed back to the object references.

With a custom converter I managed to get the serialization working as I want. But when deserializing I have the problem that I can't figure out how to acces the already deserialized list of MyListItem to reference the objects inside the list.

Here is what I got so far:

```
public class MyListItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ListIdOnlyConverter))]
    public List<MyListItem> Items = new List<MyListItem>();
}

public class MyWrapper
{
    public List<MyListItem> Items = new List<MyListItem>();
    public List<MyObject> Objects = new List<MyObject>();
}

public class ListIdOnlyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsClass;
    }

    // convert the List<MyListItem> to a List<[MyListItem.Id]>
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        var list = (IEnumerable<object>)value;
        foreach (var item in list)
            writer.WriteValue(GetId(item));
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    // get the item id with reflection
    private int GetId(object obj)
    {
        var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Id", typeof(int));
        if (prop != null && prop.CanRead)
        {
            return (int)prop.GetValue(obj, null);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // convert the List<[MyListItem.Id]> to a List<MyListItem>
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jArray = JArray.Load(reader);

        var list = (List<object>)existingValue;

        foreach (var entry in jArray)
        {
            // and here comes the problem
            // instead of adding new instances with just the id set I need references to the previously deserialized objects in wrapper.Items
            list.Add(new MyListItem { Id = (int)entry });
        }

        return list;
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Serialize()
{
    var wrapper = new MyWrapper();
    wrapper.Items.Add(new MyListItem { Id = 1, Name = "Item 1" });
    wrapper.Items.Add(new MyListItem { Id = 2, Name = "Item 2" });
    wrapper.Items.Add(new MyListItem { Id = 3, Name = "Item 3" });

    var objectWithItem1 = new MyObject();
    objectWithItem1.Name = "objectWithItem1";
    objectWithItem1.Items.Add(wrapper.Items[0]);
    wrapper.Objects.Add(objectWithItem1);

    var objectWithItem2 = new MyObject();
    objectWithItem2.Name = "objectWithItem2";
    objectWithItem2.Items.Add(wrapper.Items[1]);
    wrapper.Objects.Add(objectWithItem2);

    var objectWithItem3 = new MyObject();
    objectWithItem3.Name = "objectWithItem3";
    objectWithItem3.Items.Add(wrapper.Items[2]);
    wrapper.Objects.Add(objectWithItem3);

    var objectWithItem1And3 = new MyObject();
    objectWithItem1And3.Name = "objectWithItem1And3";
    objectWithItem1And3.Items.Add(wrapper.Items[0]);
    objectWithItem1And3.Items.Add(wrapper.Items[2]);
    wrapper.Objects.Add(objectWithItem1And3);

    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    var text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wrapper, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, settings);

    // this is the part not working - see ListIdOnlyConvert.ReadJson(...)
    var obj = ((MyWrapper)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text, typeof(MyWrapper)));
}
```

This is the result when serialized:

```
{
    Items: [
        { "Id": 1, "Name": "Item 1" },
        { "Id": 2, "Name": "Item 2" },
        { "Id": 3, "Name": "Item 3" }
    ]
    Objects: [
        { "Name": "objectWithItem1", "Items": [1] },
        { "Name": "objectWithItem2", "Items": [2] },
        { "Name": "objectWithItem3", "Items": [3] },
        { "Name": "objectWithItem1And3", "Items": [1,3] }       
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why not use Json.Net's [built-in mechanism](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm) for preserving object references?  It doesn't work in exactly the same way that you have laid out here, but if all you're trying to do is save space and you don't care so much about the format, then it could save you a lot of time.

Comment: Preserving object references would work, yes.

But I have several lists with items and I don't like that it adds an additional field (the $id) to the items when I have already an existing id on the items.
And as far as I understand it the id is global over all objects.
That ends up in longer and longer ids as more items I add.